# Why packet is lost after nat:PREROUTING phase?

Tags: networking, iptables

I was trying to debug iptables rules of calico and found an weird problem: some packets are lost after nat:PREROUTING.

I have three pods on three different nodes, say:

edge1/net-tool-edge1: 10.22.46.41/192.168.0.16
node1/net-tool-node1: 10.22.46.16/10.234.102.161
master/net-tool-master: 10.22.46.11/10.234.79.169

I should metion there is no calico-node on edge1 and instead a fabedge-agent(another CNI) is running on it. Something wrong happened on edge1, so the packet from net-tool-edge1 were lost on node1. That's why I try to debug calico iptable rules, because I don't think a bug on fabedge can affect calico.

I debugged iptables using `trace` target as suggested by this article: https://www.opsist.com/blog/2015/08/11/how-do-i-see-what-iptables-is-doing.html

When calico works normal(net-tool-master -> net-tool-node1), I got this:

```
raw:PREROUTING:policy:3
mangle:PREROUTING:rule:1
mangle:cali-PREROUTING:rule:3
mangle:cali-from-host-endpoint:return:1
mangle:cali-PREROUTING:return:5
mangle:PREROUTING:policy:2
nat:PREROUTING:rule:1
nat:cali-PREROUTING:rule:1
nat:cali-fip-dnat:return:1
nat:cali-PREROUTING:return:2
nat:PREROUTING:rule:2
nat:KUBE-SERVICES:return:18
nat:PREROUTING:policy:4
mangle:FORWARD:policy:1
filter:FORWARD:rule:1
filter:cali-FORWARD:rule:1
filter:cali-FORWARD:rule:2
filter:cali-from-hep-forward:return:1
filter:cali-FORWARD:rule:4
filter:cali-to-wl-dispatch:rule:3
filter:cali-tw-cali20fd069ebc8:rule:3
filter:cali-tw-cali20fd069ebc8:rule:4
filter:cali-pri-_zbxMTbNMDRyfczFBup:rule:1
filter:cali-pri-_zbxMTbNMDRyfczFBup:rule:2
filter:cali-tw-cali20fd069ebc8:rule:5
filter:cali-FORWARD:rule:5
filter:cali-to-hep-forward:return:1
filter:cali-FORWARD:rule:6
filter:cali-cidr-block:return:1
filter:cali-FORWARD:return:7
filter:FORWARD:rule:2
filter:FABEDGE-FORWARD:return:4
filter:FORWARD:rule:3
filter:KUBE-FORWARD:return:5
filter:FORWARD:rule:4
filter:KUBE-SERVICES:return:1
filter:FORWARD:rule:5
filter:KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES:return:1
filter:FORWARD:rule:6
filter:DOCKER-USER:return:1
filter:FORWARD:rule:7
filter:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1:return:2
filter:FORWARD:rule:12
mangle:POSTROUTING:rule:1
mangle:cali-POSTROUTING:rule:1
mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:2
nat:POSTROUTING:rule:1
nat:cali-POSTROUTING:rule:1
nat:cali-fip-snat:return:1
nat:cali-POSTROUTING:rule:2
nat:cali-nat-outgoing:return:2
nat:cali-POSTROUTING:return:4
nat:POSTROUTING:rule:2
nat:FABEDGE-POSTROUTING:return:3
nat:POSTROUTING:rule:3
nat:KUBE-POSTROUTING:rule:1
nat:POSTROUTING:policy:5
```

And when packets are lost(net-tool-edge1 -> net-tool-node1), the trace is like this:

```
raw:PREROUTING:policy:4
mangle:PREROUTING:rule:1
mangle:cali-PREROUTING:rule:3
mangle:cali-from-host-endpoint:return:1
mangle:cali-PREROUTING:return:5
mangle:PREROUTING:policy:2
nat:PREROUTING:rule:1
nat:cali-PREROUTING:rule:1
nat:cali-fip-dnat:return:1
nat:cali-PREROUTING:return:2
nat:PREROUTING:rule:2
nat:KUBE-SERVICES:return:18
nat:PREROUTING:policy:4
```

It seems packets are dropped by default policy, but the default policy of PREROUTING of nat table is `ACCEPT`:

```
[root@node1 ~]# iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    cali-PREROUTING  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* cali:6gwbT8clXdHdC1b1 */
2    KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes service portals */
3    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
```

In fact this `nat:PREROUTING:policy:4` also appeared in the normal trace, so I thinks this might not be the reason.

I really counld't figure out what happened. There was also no conntrack records found.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why packet is lost is because there is no route and rp_filter is turned on. After setting rp_filter is turned off, the packets finally can arrive net-tool-node1